# How to filter not %in%?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe **df** with an ID column. I use the following code to filter the values of **df** contained in a vector of **ID**:

```
df <- df %>% 
  filter(ID %in% vector)
```

How can I filter to get all the df values that have ID not contained in vector instead than contained in vector?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use ! to invert a condition:

```
df <- df %>% 
  filter(! ID %in% vector)
```

Comment: I always found this confusing at first because I wanted to put `!%in%` which is **not** the correct syntax. The key is that `x %in% y` produces a `logical` `vector` which you then negate by adding `!` at the front.

Answer (score 7):

Arguably, the most elegant solution is achieved by [leveraging functional programming](https://rdrr.io/r/base/funprog.html) capabilities available in R and using `Negate` to create a `%nin%` function that will return results reverse to those that the are provided by `%in%`.

```r
library("tidyverse")
`%nin%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl %nin% c(6, 4))
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> ... (truncated for brevity)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you are working in [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org) you may want to consider using [`negate`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/negate.html). Tidyverse functions play nicely with each other and usually there subtle differences in implementation<sup>1</sup>

```r
library("tidyverse")
`%nin%` <- negate(`%in%`)
mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl %nin% c(6, 4))
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> ... (truncated for brevity)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Functionals, [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html).